# How to open an activity from a recyclerview item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am trying to open another activity from a RecyclerView. I'm not understanding how to use the `sendMessage()` method to start the new activity. I have used the method in with another button to open a new activity all I want to do is to open up a the same activity but just with a different activity.

I have tried pluggin the `sendMessage()` method into the listener. I have tried using an intent.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buildRecyclerView();
}

public void buildRecyclerView(){
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvGoals);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mAdapter = new RVAdapter(mGoal);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RVAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAddClick(int position) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainGoalInfo.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}
```

Recycler View adapter:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.GoalViewHolder> {
    private List<Goals> goalsRVA;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
        void onAddClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public RVAdapter(List<Goals> goalsRVA){
        this.goalsRVA=goalsRVA;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return goalsRVA.size();
    }

    @Override
    public GoalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,int i){
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.goal_view,viewGroup,false);
        GoalViewHolder gvh=new GoalViewHolder(v,mListener);
        return gvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GoalViewHolder goalViewHolder, int i){
        goalViewHolder.goalDescriptionRV.setText(goalsRVA.get(i).getDescription());
        goalViewHolder.goalDueDateRV.setText(goalsRVA.get(i).getGoalDate());
        goalViewHolder.goalTitleRV.setText(goalsRVA.get(i).getGoal());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView){
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public static class GoalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView cv;
        TextView goalDescriptionRV;
        TextView goalDueDateRV;
        TextView goalTitleRV;
        ImageView mAddSubGoal;

        GoalViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener){
            super(itemView);
            cv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.shit_view);
            goalTitleRV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            goalDueDateRV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.dueDate);
            goalDescriptionRV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            mAddSubGoal=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ADDSUBGOAL);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            mAddSubGoal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onAddClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could my answer not solve the problem? It should & if it didn't, please let us know the error you may be facing with. If it helped, kindly accept the answer, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the desired action inside `setOnClickListener()` method of your `GoalViewHolder`. You can initialize the adapter with the context from your activity:

```
mAdapter = new RVAdapter(mGoal, this);
```

Recycler View adapter:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.GoalViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    ...
    public RVAdapter(List<Goals> goalsRVA, Context mContext){
        this.goalsRVA=goalsRVA;
        this.mContext=mContext
    }
```

And in your `GoalViewHolder`:

```
GoalViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener){
            ...
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,MainGoalInfo.class);
                    ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                    ...
                }
            });
...
}
```

Comment: No it didn't work for me. Now I am getting errors for `mContext` and im getting an error in my `GoalViewHolder` spedifically when im instantiating it. I feel like im not completely understanding button clicks when it comes to Recyclerview.

Comment: What are the errors that you're getting, as you said, with `mContext`? Please put it here so that I can understand.

Comment: I fixed the `GoalViewHolder` error it happened because I didn't delete the `final OnItemClickListener listener`. I am specifically getting the error Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: **Fixed** the last error. Now I'm just trying to get startActivityForResult to work.

Comment: Okay edited the answer again, please have a look. Use `((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent,1)` since you've passed the context from your Activity to your Adapter.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that from inside onbindViewHolder

Send the context at the adapter  constructor